# Calculate the position of a point after it is rotated about two axes in 3D?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d

This image represents the starting configuration, looking down at the $x$-$y$ plane.
[image: Image of two axes in x-y plane]

Point $p$ starts at the specified coordinates in the $x$-$y$ plane.

The first 'axis' is located in the $x$-$y$ plane, rotated 35° about the $z$-axis. The point is rotated about this axis by angle $θ$ such that it moves 'up' in the $z$ direction.

The point is then rotated about the x-axis by another angle $α$, again moving 'up' in the z direction.

I am trying to create a function $z_2(θ)$ which gives the z coordinate of the point's final position in terms of $θ$, which is my independent variable. All other values are known constants. I don't know if it helps to know the actual values, but here they are:

$x_1 = 0.005216$
$y_1 = 0.005224$
$α = 7.902869°$

The value of $θ$ will be small, roughly between 5° and 15°. Neither rotation will move the point out of the first quadrant where it is initially depicted.

Is it possible to solve this with trigonometry? I am hoping to avoid needing quaternions.

Comment: How familiar are you with linear algebra and matrix multiplication? Each rotation is given by a rotation matrix, which [there are formulae for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle).

Comment: I've heard of those, lol. If that's the only way then I guess I'll have to dig in.

Comment: You can also get away with not using matrices, but if you know about them it makes the calculation a bit more "routine". You could do it by observing that what you're doing is equivalent to this: "first rotate by 35 degrees about the $z$-axis, then rotate by $\theta$ degrees about the $y$-axis, then rotate by $-35$ degrees about the $z$-axis, then rotate by $\alpha$ degrees about the $x$-axis." (being careful about directions). It's not so bad to work out what happens when you rotate a point about a coordinate axis - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes_in_two_dimensions).

Comment: That method makes sense to me, and I think I can handle that reasonably enough. The only thing I'm not entirely clear on are the directions of those two 35° rotations. Wouldn't the first one be -35, or counter-clockwise, so that the arbitrary axis then lines up with the y-axis?

Comment: I was being a bit lazy about the directions which is why I said you have to be careful :). It depends on which way around you think of the axis, and which way you consider to be the "positive" direction to rotate. Usually in maths "anticlockwise" is the positive direction. I think that looking from "above", you should indeed rotate clockwise and then anticlockwise by $35$ degrees. (if you work out the details of this feel free to self-post an answer by the way)

Comment: You're right, anyways. I was able to complete my calculations with a spreadsheet, doing each rotation step by step using the formulae from the linked wikipedia page. I suppose I could combine each step and simplify it into an actual formula, but I think the method itself is more valuable than the specific implementation I needed.